# Splitting a String by Comma, then put it in a Treemap

Tags: java, arrays, string, split, treemap

I have a file called "marathon", where I have 7 keys:

- sex
- time
- athlete
- athlete's nationality
- date
- city
- country

splitted by a comma ",". I have to put the second key (time) in a Treemap.
At the moment I am just trying to show only the time in the console.

So here is my code:

```java
public class Text {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException  { 
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("marathon"));
            String str;
            str = in.readLine();
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                //System.out.println(str);
                String[] ar=str.split(",");
                System.out.println(ar[0]);
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("File Read Error");
        }    
    }
}
```

This is what a line of the text looks like:

> M, 2:30:57.6, Harry Payne, GBR, 1929-07-05, Stamford Bridge, England

When I start the program of my code example and put in `System.out.println(ar[0]);` `a[0]` shows me the first line in the console so M's and F's. But when I put `a[1]` there is an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
```

Comment: You try to read each line twice: every time this code is called: `str = in.readLine();`

Comment: Could there be a line of your text that doesn't follow the comma-separated format you illustrated above? In that case, your array may only contain one element. You probably want to debug your code.

Comment: @GalAbra that's true, but wouldn't explain the 1 element array would it?

Comment: @Mena No, but that's a start for debugging :)

Comment: @GalAbra okay, but why is it okay for the first row then?

Comment: Probably it tries to read row number 1, but there is only row number 0 in your file?

Comment: @GalAbra totally, because OP will always miss on content for 1st line. But their most immediate problem is the unexpected 1-length array though.

Comment: @GalAbra i changed it so it works the same as before. thx for that debugging tip.

Comment: @Simon You would to well to check the length of the *ar* array before you try to access elements in it.

Comment: @Simon if the spit method does not find the *separator* given it puts the *complete string* (line) into the first array element. I suspect you have *empty lines* in your input tho the "full content" of that line is an *empty string*.

Comment: how can i get all lines in a array? and then just read the second line out and later put it in a treemap?

Comment: *"how can i get all lines in a array?"* see [File.readAllLines()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-)

Comment: and then i can split the List?

Comment: it does not make much sense when you say that all the answers bellow are not working, it seems like a strait forward problem. Could you please provide the data in question, or at lest the line that causes the exception.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, you do readline **twice** before you get into the body of the loop, so you will miss the first line.

But you are also not checking that readline resulted in a properly formatted line. It may be an empty line or a line that in some other way does not result in an array that you expect.

So you should add an if-statement that checks that you have what you expected, like so...

```
public class Text {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException  {

        try {
           BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("marathon"));
            String str = "";
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] ar=str.split(",");
                if(ar.length >= 7) {
                    System.out.println(ar[0] + ", " + ar[1]);
                }
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("File Read Error");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much but this doesn't work either for me :(   I get the point  and I deleted the first readline() but I don't get the second part. Why does it work for column 1 then? It goes through all lines there too. And it knows when the new line starts and then gives me lots of M's and F's

Comment: @Simon I messed up... I wrote **str.length** but I meant **ar.length**. Edited. Try now.

Comment: Yes. Works perfectly. I had to change the printline that it prints ar[1] and now it prints only the times in the console... Thx so much. Do you know if i can just take this and put it in a treemap?

Comment: I need to ask you this @Simon : what is the task you are trying to solve here? Why are you asking in the first place? Because a quick search reveals that [you are not exactly the first to use this particular set of data](https://www.unix.com/302961461-post1.html). If this is homework, a work sample test or in any other way a task that you need to solve by yourself, people at StackOverflow are doing you a **disservice** by solving it for you. So... before anything else: what do you need this program for?

Comment: I have to do this as an homework. What is wrong with asking other people to help you if you are stuck and can't get the prolem solved at this point? I get the point but i am just searching for an advice for this particullar exception not for an complete solution for my task...

Comment: @Simon I did not say it was **wrong**, only that I would tailor my answer according to whether this was the case or not. So, with that in mind: what do you think? Do you think you can put the values that you have extracted in the map now or not? To help you answer that: what do you need in order to put things in a map? When you know what you need, ask: do you have those things, yes or no? If yes, go right ahead. If no, how and you get the things you need?

Comment: Okay, thank you :)  For a map I need a key and a value i think. So the key would be my "time" column from my marathon.txt. I don't really understand the value part. So i thought that every key get's his value automatically but I think i am wrong at that point. I am thinking about a new variable that is the value and that increases everytime a key is added to the Map. @MichaelK Thank you for helping me out I didn't mean to be rude

Comment: I think the problem now is that it is part of an String Array am I right? So i need to get a string which i can put in the map

Comment: @Simon Yes, whenever you put something in a map you need a key and a value. The key is what you use to look up the value in the map later on; it is what you use to find the value in the map. As for what value to use... look at the task description. What does the task description say you are supposed to store in the map?

Comment: I have to use the time as the key of the map. Then i am asked if the output of the map (the times) is correctly sorted or not. Later I should only output the runners starting for GER and then only the runners who's last name start with C. @MichaelK

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code below. It's working for me.

You should have read the line only once in the while loop.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Text {

         @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException  {


             try {
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("marathon"));
                    String str;
                    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        //System.out.println(str);
                        String[] ar=str.split(",");
                        System.out.println(ar[0]);
                        System.out.println(ar[1]);
                    }
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("File Read Error");
                }

         }
}
```

Comment: doesn't work for me :/ but thx for you're answer. what did you change btw?

Answer (score 0):

```
SortedMap<String, String[]> map = new TreeMap<>();
Path path = Paths.get("marathon");
Files.lines(path, Charsets.defaultCharset())
    .map(line -> line.split(",\\s*"))
    .peek(words -> {
        if (words.length != 7) {
            Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).info("Line wrong: " + line);
        }
    })
    .filter(words -> words.length == 7)
    .forEach(words -> map.put(word[1], words));
```

However there are CSV reader classes out there, that can handle quoted fields with commas and such.

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 just for fun

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import static java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset;
import static java.lang.System.out;
import static java.nio.file.Files.lines;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Map<String, String[]> map = new TreeMap<>(  );

        try( Stream<String> lines = lines(Paths.get("marathon"), defaultCharset())){

            lines.map(line -> line.split( "," )).forEach( entry -> map.put(entry[1], entry ));

            map.values().forEach( entry -> out.println(Arrays.toString( entry )) );
        }
    }
}
```